# How Can I use Django Filter Backend url parameters fields for multible models connected via foreignkey connection?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have an master and masterDetail model given in below;

```
class Master(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_user')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_company')
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_department')

class MasterDetail(models.Model):
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_master')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_user')
    recordtypes = models.ForeignKey(RecordTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_recordtypes')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to filter data using these two model fields at the same time using  Django Filter Backend url parameters. The url has two model field parameters like;

```
http://127.0.0.1:8003/api/master/detail/query/page/list?search=&pages=1&page_size=14&company_code=XXX&recordtypes=general
```

This is also myview;

```
class masterListAllView(generics.ListAPIView):
    search_fields = ['company_company_code']
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_class = MasterFilter
    serializer_class = masterDetailAllSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

I try to write filterset_class = MasterFilter for filtering but this is only work for filtering master model.

Comment: We need more details. Do you have any view? If you can't start, try to write simple functional view with filtering, then try to use generic views.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to filter on recordtypes(MasterDetail) and company(Master).

Try this

```
MasterDetail.objects.filter(recordtypes__name='General', master__company__name="Test')
```

here "__name" is the name of field in record/company table.